# implement SlideView using Nuget Package on a CLICK EVENT in wp8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

How to implement this SlideView using Nuget Package on a CLICK EVENT in wp8 ? Please share some answer.

```
<Grid Background="Teal"
        Width="400" />

<Grid Background="Tomato" />

<Grid Background="LightYellow" />

<Grid Background="YellowGreen"
        Width="400"/>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try this [tutorial](http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.in/2013/08/add-lateral-menus-to-windows-phone.html), It Add side menus to an Windows Phone application (similar to the Facebook app)
also source code for the project is given there
hope you will found it helpfull